# How to remake UIButton to use UIButton.Configuration

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton, ios15

In the context of updating legacy code to modern standards, I have encountered a scenario where I need to refactor a UIButton creation and configuration process. The original implementation is as follows:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "MyIcon"), for: .normal)
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -8, left: -40, bottom: -8, right: 0)
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -60, bottom: 0, right: 0)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.sizeToFit()
```

I would appreciate guidance on transitioning this code to use the UIButton.Configuration paradigm introduced in iOS 15, ensuring that the visual layout and interaction behaviors of the button remain consistent with the original implementation. What approach or specific configurations would be required to achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question showing what you have tried so far. Explain what issues you are having in the conversion that you can't get working correctly. Perhaps includes images of the original and new buttons showing the issues you are having as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to add an image of the button to make it easier to create the code but based on what you explained...

### iOS 15.0+

`UIButton.Configuration` contains all the customization options available with other methods, such as `setTitle(_:for:)`, and can serve as a replacement for all those methods you provided.

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    
    configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .link // color of the button background
    configuration.baseForegroundColor = .white // color of the text and image
    
    configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "star")
    
    configuration.title = "Star Button"
    
    configuration.imagePlacement = .leading
    configuration.contentInsets.leading = 40
    configuration.imagePadding = 20
    
    configuration.titlePadding = 20 // 20 starting from the end of the image
    
    button.configuration = configuration
    
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

[Button screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju6bV.png)

I'd highly suggest you to take a look at those sites as they have examples on most of the cases:

[UseYourLoaf UIButton.Configuration](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/button-configuration-in-ios-15/)

[Sarunw UIButton.Configuration](https://sarunw.com/posts/new-way-to-style-uibutton-in-ios15/)